# How to change server for my application in cloudbees?

Tags: cloudbees

I want to change the server from Jboss7.1 to Tomcat7 in cloudbees. What are the ways to do this? To mention that my application is already deployed and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy in Tomcat 7 through the [CloudBees SDK](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK) using this command.

```
bees app:deploy -t tomcat7 -a app.war
```

Be aware that your app should be adapted to work with both containers.